# Detect TextView Scrolling to Show a Button in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a TextView and a hidden button within a UIView, and I'm trying to detect when the user scrolls down to the bottom of a long list of text and to show the hidden button when they reach the bottom. I saw some old posts on how it was done in Obj-C using scrollViewDidScroll, but not really sure how to do that with swift, or how to do it with a TextView instead of a ScrollView. Any help would be great as I haven't gone very far with this one.

So far this is my attempt at translating the obj-c post to swift, but it hasn't worked for me, in fact I'm not even sure when the function is called:

```
 import UIKit

 class MainVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.delegate = self


    }

   func scrollViewDidScroll(textV: UIScrollView) {

        if (textV.contentOffset.y >= textV.contentSize.height - textV.frame.size.height)
        {
            button.isHidden = false
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: 1st - @IBOutlet var textView: UIScrollView! , but func scrollViewDidScroll(textV: UITextView) both are different . either try both scrollview or both textview . This code will work .

Comment: Hi, I fixed it in the example. Tried it in my code too, but it didn't work. Thanks any way.

Comment: is it calling didscroll method ? and check the outlet and delegates are connected for the UITextView .

Comment: I tried a print statement in the scrollViewDidScroll function, but it's not called even though the outlet is connected and the textview.delegate is set in viewDidLoad :(

Comment: set delegate in XIB or in storyboard to the mainVC view .

Comment: I had that enabled in storyboard already so that wasn't the problem :(

Comment: I'm wondering if it's just not working because it is a TextView?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`UITextView` is subclass of `UIScrollView` and if you look to declaration, you will see, that it is `UIScrollViewDelegate` by default, so you can remove the `UIScrollViewDelegate` at the declaration of your controller. Instead, make your controller `UITextViewDelegate` which allows it to call scrollViewDidScrollMethod.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView! {
        didSet {
            textView.delegate = self
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            button.hidden = true
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        button.hidden = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.height < scrollView.contentSize.height
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to Swift, I also appreciate you how declared the starting state and delegate for the textView and button in the IBOutlet statements rather than in viewDidLoad as I wasn't aware one could do that so Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

float bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height

if (bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {

    self.yourButtonName.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: paste this code. Expected declaration error comes in case of code syntax error.

Comment: do I have to change any of the text? I'm still getting the same error, even after I rename the button.

Comment: @Maksym Musiienko  scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.height < scrollView.contentSize.height >> I think this line of code shows the position of scroll view's scroll is not at bottom. am i correct?

Answer (score 2):

If the button is in the last of view(self.view) then I think you have to check that your contentOffset point is at the bottom of contentSize. So you could probably do something like:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView { 
    float bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y +scrollView.frame.size.height;       
    if (bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
        self.yourButtonName.hidden = true 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to swift. Where do I fit this in?

Comment: (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView { } this method is a delegate method of scroll view. dont paste this code inside any function/method block.this is itself a function so paste it anywhere inside class (after viewdidload and view will appear).

Comment: (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView { float bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height; if (bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {   self.yourButtonName.hidden = true   } }

Comment: I tried it, but I get an error saying: Expected Declaration.